# fetch api returns `function text() { [native code] }`

Tags: javascript, html, promise, fetch-api

im new with fetch api and i've got a tiny problem.

```
document.getElementById('getText').addEventListener('click',function(){
    fetch('text.txt')
        .then(function(res){
            return res.text
        }).then(function(data){
            document.body.innerHTML += `<br><br>${data}`
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err)
        })
})
```

this is my code. it returns this: 
`function text() { [native code] }`
i want it to returns the content not this. i dont know what should i do !?
sorry for asking a dumb question.
thanks

Comment: `.text` is a *function*, not an ordinary property, you must call it

Answer (score 4):

The primary issue is that [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) is a *function*, you need to call it, not just return it:

```
return res.text();
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^^
```

---

A couple of other suggestions:

1. Check `ok` before calling it (unless you want the `text` of the error page), thanks to a footgun in the `fetch` API I describe [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

2. I strongly recommend **not** using `+=` with `innerHTML`. When you do that, the browser has to do this:

- Loop through all of the elements in the container you use `innerHTML` on (in this case, the entire `document.body`) and create an HTML string to represent them.
- Add your string to the end of the string from Step 1
- Destroy all of the existing elements within the container
- Parse the string from Step 2, creating new elements
- Put those elements in the container

In the process, it destroys any event handlers on the existing content.

Instead, use `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<br><br>${data}`)
```

3. Finally, using arrow functions for the promise settlement handlers would make things a bit more concise (but it's entirely up to you).

Putting all of those together:

```
document.getElementById('getText').addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch('text.txt')
        .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status)
            }
            return res.text();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            document.body.innerHTML += `<br><br>${data}`;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```